# To disable url for particular subcategory in magento cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

just got handed a magento site to update. No experience with the cart, so I hope these questions aren't too simplistic. Did search around a bit and haven't been able to find straightforward answers
 => For Some of my accessories showing in magento cart i does not want link on their title and image so how i made this dynamically.
Any help is appreciable

Comment: Do not understand the question. Please clarify.

Comment: Are you trying to disable the link to that product detail page on certain items in your cart (link on item title and image)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have create a function in /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer.php

```
    public function getCustumcatId()
    {
    $proid=$this->getProduct()->getId();
    $categoryIds=$this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds($proid);
    foreach($categoryIds as $categoryId)
    {
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    }
    return  $category->getName();
    }
```

and call it on default.phtml of cart 
after getting name i use if and else to remove link thanks for help and comment